# Square brackets in logical expression

Tags: logic

We have been tasked with setting up a truth table for the following logical expression

$$\large[(P\lor \lnot Q)\to Q]\land P$$

However we are unsure of what the square brackets mean. Can anyone clarify this for us?

Comment: Brackets mean priority when it cames to evaluation (and manipulation).

Comment: So the parenthesis first, and then the brackets come second?

Comment: Yes. Parentheses and brackets mean the same thing: $((P\vee\neg Q)\rightarrow Q)\wedge P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They work just like the parentheses ( and ) ... some people find it useful to use different sets so you can more easily see which goes with which ... so sometimes you  will also see { and }  as well, as in something like

$$\{ [A \rightarrow (B \land C)] \lor D \} \leftrightarrow [B \lor (C \rightarrow B)]$$

which may indeed be easier to read than if we strictly use parentheses:

$$((A \rightarrow (B \land C)) \lor D) \leftrightarrow (B \lor (C \rightarrow B))$$